# Find the $k$ of the formula $k\pi ^m=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2n+1+\frac{a}{3})^m}+\frac{1}{(2n+1-\frac{a}{3})^m}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory

$$k\pi ^m=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2n+1+\frac{a}{3})^m}+\frac{1}{(2n+1-\frac{a}{3})^m}$$ when $a$ an even integer number if $$a\geq 4 $$ $$gcd(a,3)=1$$
I want to find $k$ with $m$

if $m$ is an even integer number

Hint: for $m=2$ the $k=1$

Comment: I think the summation part amounts to a geometric series, since the denominator is clearly $>1$. Try summing that part first. Unless the entire thing is supposed to be inside the summation? Can you edit, putting parentheses in where they might be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** [Prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023193) that, for $m=2$, $S(a)=\bigg[\dfrac\pi2\sec\bigg(a\dfrac\pi6\bigg)\bigg]^2$, then differentiate both sides with regard to *a* an even number of times.

Comment: ok,but can you get  the relationship between $k$ and $m$. I got $k=5/6$ when $m=4$, and $k=91/120$ when $m=6$, but I couldn't get the general relationship.

Comment: @Ehegh: I do not foresee the existence of a “simple” relation between the two.

Comment: There's my solution in the cited link, so +1. :D

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$$\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(z-n)^2}$$
it follows that:
$$\frac{\pi^2}{\cos^2(\pi z)}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{2}-z-n\right)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{2}-z-n\right)^2}+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{3}{2}-z+n\right)^2}\right)\tag{1}$$
so we can find the value of $k\in\mathbb{Q}$ by differentiating the previous identity.